# Passing args to a JS command line utility (Node or Narwhal)

Tags: javascript, node.js, narwhal

I want to use NodeJS or Narwhal to create a JS utility which takes an argument, like so:

```
$ node myscript.js http://someurl.com/for/somefile.js
```

or

```
$ js myscript.js http://someurl.com/for/somefile.js
```

but I'm wondering how I can get that argument within my script, or if that is even possible atm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Node.JS, that information is available in [`process.argv`](http://NodeJS.Org/docs/v0.4.2/api/process.html#process.argv).

Answer (score 2):

`process.arg[2]` should be the reference. Check for `process.argv.length` to see if it's `3`.

[Docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/process.html#process.argv)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist), a module for node.js that makes processing args a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

This things now are very easy to do, using [stdio](https://npmjs.org/package/stdio) module for NodeJS.